# Gradient texture loses effects in linked smoke simulation group

Tags: node-editor, smoke-simulation

I have created a smoke simulation with the following node-setup as the material.

[image]

The three nodes on the far left allow the lump in the center of the smoke simulation to lose their density. The texture coordinate utilizes an empty to control the area that loses density. I named this empty the transparent control.

This is the smoke simulation without the transparent control.
[image]

And this is the smoke simulation with the transparent control.
[image]

The transparent control loses its effects when I link the smoke simulation group into another file. This group consists of the domain, flow object and transparent control. Has anyone else encountered similar issues or know what I might be doing wrong?

Here is a picture of the linked smoke group that shows the lump in the center. 
[image]